# Java XML transformation interface

Tags: java, xml, dom, transformation, xslt

I need to transform a XML. Usually I would use Saxon and a XSLT 2.0 stylehsheet for this. The transformations I have to do involve side-effects and are stateful and manipulate the contens of nodes, so implementing a XPath function doesn't make that much sense.

I decided to implement a transformer class for this purpose. I found `javax.xml.transform` provides a standard interface for this, but is targeted towards implementing a XSLT processor (it requires a `TransformerFactory` and `Transformer` for each transformation) and seems complex and unnecessary for my purpose.

Is there a general XML (DOM) transformation interface which I could use instead of inventing my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javax.xml.transform interface is the standard means in Java for performing an XSLT transform on an XML document.  Since it does not appear that your transform will be XSLT based, this is not the correct API for you.

Programmers occassionally implement their own versions of Source and Result to hook into standard javax.xml.transform transformers, but this is not your use case.

Is there a particular API you are hoping to integrate with?  If not you will be better off desigining your own API.

Comment: No, I don't want to integrate with something specific, but I just wanted to make sure that there's nothing I'm missing.

Comment: I'm a big supporter of standard interfaces.  I lead an object-to-XML product that implements the JAXB (JSR-222) & SDO (JSR-235) standards.  But I don't see any reason for your DOM converter to implement a specific interface.